# Create a Clone/Duplicate copy of MSMQ message using powershell

Tags: powershell, msmq

I am working on a powershell utility that will maintain a minimum number of messages on a private queue by adding duplicate copies of existing message as and when the queue gets depleted by a consumer process.

Here is what I am doing

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging") | out-null
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Text") | out-null
.
.
$enum = $queue.GetMessageEnumerator2();

while($enum.MoveNext())
{
    #Strategy 1 - Re-add existing message to queue
    $message = $enum.Current;
    $queue.Send($message);

    #Strategy 2 - Add a dummy message to queue
    $messageClone = New-Object System.Messaging.Message;
    $queue.Send($messageClone);

    logInfo("Number of messages in Queue - " + $queue.GetAllMessages().Length);
}
.
.
```

I don't think this is working as the total number of message remain the same after adding the messages to the Queue. Could you please point me to the issues with this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was not creating the duplicate message in the right way. Here is the solution to this question

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging") | out-null
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Text") | out-null
.
.
$enum = $queue.GetMessageEnumerator2();

while($enum.MoveNext())
{
    $tran = new-object System.Messaging.MessageQueueTransaction;
    $tran.Begin();

    #$msgContent
    $message = $enum.Current;

    $msg = new-object System.Messaging.Message;
    $msg.BodyStream = $message.BodyStream;
    $queue.Send($msg, $tran);

    $tran.Commit();          
}
.
.
```